# Conditional formatting between two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Hi sorry I just really need some answer for this question. I'm only using my phone.

In the first pic is the simple conditional formatting that I use. Cell value with specific text

But in picture #2 is what I would like to happen. Even in the blank between there would be a color. Not sure if this is possible but I would like to hear from you guys.

Thank you.

Picture #1

[image]

Picture #2

[image]

Comment: What is the condition you currently use? Please explain what the new condition should be.

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad. My formula is =OR(A2='ML')        but what i would like to do. For example ML is placed B2 and F2. Is it possible that it can also highlight the cell C2,D2,E2.

Comment: What would happen if you had more than two non-blank cells in a row?

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe . Do you mean if i put another ML?

Comment: Yes - would they all have colour between them? Does it have to be ML or can it be any character string?

Comment: @TomSharpe any character would do but i would prefer ML VL SL because im using this for the leave planner. No it only highlight the specific character. Not sure what would be the correct formula if that formula exist.

Comment: UP still need answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rules would work for the examples shown:

```
=OR(A2="ML",ISODD(COUNTIF($A2:A2,"ML")))
```

and

```
=OR(A2="LWOP",ISODD(COUNTIF($A2:A2,"LWOP")))
```

[image]

but the problem is if you had a single instance of (say) LWOP like this:

[image]

there is no way to tell which is a single instance and which denotes an interval.

I don't believe there is any way of resolving this except by using a separate code for one-off events like LWOPS and changing the formula to:

```
=OR(A2="LWOP",A2="LWOPS",ISODD(COUNTIF($A2:A2,"LWOP")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can play with concatenation, something like:

```
=CONCAT(B2:$XFD2)  // concatenate from the cell itself to the most right
=CONCAT($A2:B2)    // concatenate from the most left to the cell itself
```

- The cells, more to the left, will have an empty cell result.
- Cell "B2" will be wrong (value "MLML") for the first, but correct for the second formula.
- The cells in between will be correct (value "ML").
- Cell "F2" will be correct for the first, but wrong (value "MLML") for the second formula.
- The cells, more to the right, will have an empty cell result.

=> using an `OR()` function will give a correct result, and that `OR()`-based formula can be used as a formula for the conditional formatting:

[image]